# Padding pandas groupby with zeros for inconsistent date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have car rental booking data, of this form:

```
location  |  day_of_drive |  day_of_reservation  |  number_of_bookings
-------------------------------------------------------------------
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  24-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  26-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  29-12-2014          |  3
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  30-12-2014          |  2
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  31-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  29-12-2014          |  2
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  31-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  01-01-2015          |  1
bar       |  25-06-2016   |  03-07-2016          |  1
.
.
.
```

What I want is to pad this dataset to include dates where 0 bookings were made.

The data frame is already sorted, first by `location`, then by `day_of_drive`, then by `day_of_reservation`.

What I want is an efficient way to pad with zero values the `day_of_reservation` variable **between the first observed value of this variable, which corresponds to the first booking for this** `day_of_drive`/`location` **pair, and the** `day_of_drive` **, for a given pair of** `location` **and** `day_of_drive` itself. I have come across solutions using unstacking, then using `fillna(0)`, then stacking back up, but I don't think I can use these as each pair of `location` and `day_of_drive` has a different min and max date I want to pad between.

Desired output:

```
location  |  day_of_drive |  day_of_reservation  |  number_of_bookings
-------------------------------------------------------------------
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  24-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  25-12-2014          |  0
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  26-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  27-12-2014          |  0
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  28-12-2014          |  0
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  29-12-2014          |  3
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  30-12-2014          |  2
foo       |  01-01-2015   |  31-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  29-12-2014          |  2
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  30-12-2014          |  0
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  31-12-2014          |  1
foo       |  02-01-2015   |  01-01-2015          |  1
bar       |  25-06-2016   |  03-07-2016          |  1
bar       |  25-06-2016   |  04-07-2016          |  0
.
.
.
```

I have a feeling the solution is with a `groupby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following with `set_index`, `groupby`, and `resample`:

```
#First make sure day_of_reservation is a datetime dtype:
df['day_of_reservation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day_of_reservation'])

df.set_index('day_of_reservation')\
  .groupby(['location','day_of_drive'], sort=False)['number_of_bookings']\
  .resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      location     day_of_drive day_of_reservation  number_of_bookings
0   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-24                 1.0
1   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-25                 0.0
2   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-26                 1.0
3   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-27                 0.0
4   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-28                 0.0
5   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-29                 3.0
6   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-30                 2.0
7   foo           01-01-2015            2014-12-31                 1.0
8   foo           02-01-2015            2014-12-29                 2.0
9   foo           02-01-2015            2014-12-30                 0.0
10  foo           02-01-2015            2014-12-31                 1.0
11  foo           02-01-2015            2015-01-01                 1.0
12  bar           25-06-2016            2016-03-07                 1.0
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do but couldn't figure out the resample. Saving it, well done.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df['date_of_reservation'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_reservation'])

df_date = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_of_reservation', freq="d"))['number_of_bookings'].mean())
df_date=df_date.reset_index()

df2=pd.merge(df,df_date[['date_of_reservation']], on='date_of_reservation', how='right').sort_values('date_of_reservation')
df2.loc[df2['number_of_bookings'].isnull(), 'number_of_bookings'] = 0
df2.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```